# Is the step counter running in the background as default?

Tags: android, android-sensors

I created an activity and implemented the basic step counter from Android.

All the code is inside the activity, i did not create any service or a like.

So the question is, does the app run in the background even though that i created no code for it?

I did some testing and it seems it does, but i am not 100% sure if that is the case.

Here is my code:

```
    private TextView count;

    // is inside my onCreate
    count = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mTextField);
    sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        activityRunning = true;
        Sensor countSensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER);
        if(countSensor != null) {
            sensorManager.registerListener(this, countSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Count sensor not available!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        activityRunning = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        if(activityRunning) {
            count.setText(String.valueOf(event.values[0]));
        }
    }
```

I am aware that the `onPause()` method set `activityRunning = false`, however i still can turn-off/lock-the-screen, and walk around and get the steps.

I find this a bit confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `unrigester` your Sensor during `onPause`

```
   @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
    }
```

Also if you unregister you do need to use your `boolean activityRunning`

Comment: Ok, so taking of the listener will remove the sensor running in the background?

Comment: Yep it will stop listening.

Comment: So as my code is now, it will run if i press the big button my phone, that will minimize my application. If i wanted to create an application that counted my steps, i would need NOT-TO unregister then? .. That is my final question, and i have no more :)

Comment: As long as your app is not visible to users it is always suggested to unrigester it; it is because it will continue to execute behind the hood and might lead also to "too many task running on the main thread error". Second problem: The worst case issue: It can cause memory leak since it will hold your activity and the Garbage collected cant clean the destroyed activity. :)

Comment: If your app does not require User interface, it means you need to use service like one of the popular fitness app.

Comment: Ah ok, so i have to create a Service. :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124303/discussion-between-enzokie-and-daniel).